# What is the bootstrap way to setup a hybrid page (fixed header, content (changing view), fixed footer)?

Tags: angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to create a hybrid single page application (for example like [Ionic Tabs](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)) that has fixed tabs at the bottom, a dynamic header at the top and a scalable content. Which attributes of the bootstrap framework can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this template

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
  </div>
  <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>body > .container</code>.</p>
  <p>Back to <a href="../sticky-footer">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```